# A relative path is not allowed to use COPY to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, export-to-csv

I made a function so that when I click on a button it made a "COPY TO" querie to the server. The goal is to export a table database in .csv that goes to the user downloads of my application.
I first tried to write the database table in an existing file with the following querie :

```
async function exportDatabase(req, res){
return db.any("\copy tag_7z8eq73 to 'C:\Users\New-rFid-Concept\Documents\BioTech_mathis\tag_7z8eq73.csv' delimiters '|' CSV HEADER")
.then(rows => {
        res.json(rows)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

}

But the following error is returning : "A relative path is not allowed to use COPY to a file"

From what I understand I have to write to STDOUT but when I send this request nothing happens in my VScode terminal or anything else.

I tried :

"COPY tag_7z8eq73 TO STDOUT csv header"

"COPY tag_7z8eq73 TO STDOUT"

"\copy tag_7z8eq73 TO STDOUT"

and others..

Do you know what would be the query that would allow me to create a .csv file with my node.js application?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try logging the value of `"\copy tag_7z8eq73 to 'C:\Users\New-rFid-Concept\Documents\BioTech_mathis\tag_7z8eq73.csv' delimiters '|' CSV HEADER"` and remember that ```\``` has special meaning in JS strings.

Comment: `\copy` only works with `psql`. The JDBC driver has a `COPY` API, I think. Try using that.

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry but I'm a french newbie in back-end developpment, does "logging" means making a console.log of the querie ? And how do I avoid \ ? Ty for your answer

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm already working with psql because it is a postgresql database. Do I still need this API ?

Comment: You are really calling the command line client `psql` from your Javascript code? Don't mix up `psql` and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally instead of doing with the complicated 'COPY TO' command line, I 'SELECT' the database, push it into an array, convert it to json and create a csv file using the 'vue-json-to-csv' plugin.